# Issue adding information to json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently having an issue writing data to a json file. The Code I am currently using is as follows:

```py
    if os.getenv("firstRun") == "0":
    tickets = json.loads(open('tickets.json').read())
    tickets["tickets"].append({
      totalTickets:{
        'Ticket Number': totalTickets,
        'Complaintant' : complainant,
        'Reported User': reportedID,
        'Reason': reason
      }
    })
    with open('tickets.json','a') as outfile:
      json.dump(tickets,outfile)
```

This is how I am currently writing information the the file `tickets.json`

While this works, It creates a new object called `tickets` each time. This ends up becoming an issue when trying to get information from the file(or at least the way I am getting info)
This can be seen here:

**Output**

```
{"tickets": [{
  "1": {
    "Ticket Number": 1,
    "Complaintant": "Miho#0001",
    "Reported User": 133344122986561537,
    "Reason": null}}]}

{"tickets": [{"1": {
  "Ticket Number": 1,
  "Complaintant": "Miho#0001",
  "Reported User": 711230916516773989,
  "Reason": null}}]}
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
{
  "tickets": {
    "1": {
      "Ticket Number": 1,
      "Complaintant": "Miho#0001",
      "Reported User": 133344122986561540,
      "Reason": "Cancerous Scripting"
    },
    "2": {
      "ticket Number": 2,
      "Complaintant": "Miho#0001",
      "Reported User": 133344122986561540,
      "Reason": "Cancerous Scripting"
    }
  }
}
```

In case your wondering what it is I want to do, is to have it create a new object (not tickets, but a number) every time the function is ran.

As seen from the output, it creates a whole new object, how can I fix this?

Comment: You have problem when you do `with open(..., 'a')` this is an append mode where you do not want to append to the file as text, but instead append to a json key as a value. Replace `'a'` with `'w'` instead as "write mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `totalTickets` is a variable containing the key for the new object, your code should be something like:

```
with open('tickets.json', 'r') as rf:
    tickets = json.load(rf)

tickets["tickets"][totalTickets] = {
    'Ticket Number': totalTickets,
    'Complaintant': complainant,
    'Reported User': reportedID,
    'Reason': reason
}

with open('tickets.json', 'w') as wf:
    json.dump(tickets, wf)
```

This opens the file for reading, reads it into the `tickets` dict, add a new key with the new object and overwrites the file.
You don't want to use append or a list here as you want your object to be a dictionary, as you posted in your desired output.

Comment: This does work, however I still get an issue regarding it making a new object rather then adding it to the existing `tickets` object

Comment: I'm not clear about your issue. Can you please provide me a sample of the content of `tickets.json` after running the code?

Comment: Adding it to the question now.

Comment: Correction to myself, this fix has worked! I just had some extra code that was messing it up! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you initialized `tickets` as an array. It should be an object. That is the initial content of the file should be like this

```py
{
  "tickets": {}
}
```

Now, after loading the `JSON` file say you hold the corresponding python dict in `tickets` variable. Then you can do

```py
tickets["tickets"][totalTickets] = {
  'Ticket Number': totalTickets,
  'Complaintant' : complainant,
  'Reported User': reportedID,
  'Reason': reason
}
```

After that, you are appending your data with previous data since you passing `'a'` to the second call to `open` function. Use `'w'` instead of `'a'`. This means to overwrite the previous contents of the file. This should do your job.

Comment: Despite this not being a complete answer, I have given you an upvote because it has fixed part of the issue! Many thanks